# Flink Table JDBC lookup.cache properties and related properties does not working on streaming environment

Tags: streaming, apache-flink, lookup-tables, flink-sql

When a SQL query is triggered on Streaming environment with joining both Streaming data and jdbc table, jdbc table related task finished immediately after reading all table records. When I add properties for jdbc table as lookup.cache , lookup.partial-cache.max-rows, lookup.partial-cache.expire-after-write, It will not affect on task lifecycle. It means lookup.cache mechanizm not working as expected.

I have created table as

```
CREATE  TABLE U_ZRB_C_RISKLI_MCC_0 (RISKLIMCC  STRING ,PRIMARY KEY (RISKLIMCC) NOT ENFORCED) 
  WITH ('connector' = 'jdbc' 
,'url' = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl' 
,'table-name' = 'U_ZRB_C_RISKLI_MCC_0' 
,'driver' = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' 
,'username' = 'username' 
,'password' = 'password' 
,'lookup.cache'='PARTIAL'
,'lookup.partial-cache.expire-after-write'='10s')
```

related job stops after reading table records

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you show more detail about the job, for example, DML, Flink version?

Comment: I have created 2 DML clauses , one with optimizer comment and other is without optimizer comment like below . Note that , the transaction table source is streaming source from kafka topic .

Comment: 1 : "insert into RESULT select trxUniqueNumber , ts , 364 from transactionTable T join U_ZRB_C_RISKLI_MCC_0  /*+ OPTIONS('lookup.cache'='PARTIAL','lookup.partial-cache.expire-after-write'='10s','lookup.partial-cache.cache-missing-key'='FALSE') */ U on T.trxBusinessSectorCde = U.RISKLIMCC where T.trxAmt1 >= 1000"

Comment: 2: "insert into RESULT select trxUniqueNumber , ts , 364 from transactionTable T join U_ZRB_C_RISKLI_MCC_0   U on T.trxBusinessSectorCde = U.RISKLIMCC where T.trxTermCountry <> 'TR' and T.trxTermCountry <> 'TUR' and T.trxOrigCrncyCde='USD' and T.trxAmt1 >= 1000""

Comment: The flink version on system is 1.16.0

Comment: If you want to use the lookup join in the Flink engine, I think you should refer to the syntax below: SELECT o.order_id, o.total, c.country, c.zip
FROM Orders AS o
  JOIN Customers FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF o.proc_time AS c
    ON o.customer_id = c.id;       Guide documentation: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#lookup-join

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Xianxun Ye , When I added " FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF" clause after table name , lookup functionality runs as expected as defined at link https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#lookup-join

I think flink documentation page
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/#lookup-cache
should refer the the lookup-join page also.